# Can you compare the Keys of a HashMap with a Set?

Tags: java, nested, hashmap, set, java-stream

I have a Hashmap

```
 HashMap<Integer,Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    hashmap.put(0,1);
    hashmap.put(1,1);
    hashmap.put(2,1);
    hashmap.put(3,2);
```

And a Set Set

```
 Set<Set<Integer>> set = Set.of(Set.of(0, 1, 2), Set.of(3, 4, 5), Set.of(6, 7, 8));
```

Now i want to compare my hashmap with the set and output the set which is containing all 3 keys and where the values are the same. e.g  the hashmap {0=1, 1=1, 2=1, 3=2} should output the set (0,1,2).
I tried to use stream():

```
hashmap.entrySet().stream().filter(e-> e.getValue()==1).map(Map.Entry::getKey).forEach(System.out::println);
```

But i dont know how to compare them with each other

```
 Stream<Set<Integer>> streamsets = set.stream();
  streamsets.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to find a set S in `set`, such that every element in S is a key of the map `hashmap`, and the value associated with every element of S are the same?

Comment: @Sweeper exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stream `set` instead of the map:

```
set.stream().filter(
        // s has to be a subset of the map's keys
        s -> hashmap.keySet().containsAll(s) &&

        // then we look up the associated values
        s.stream().map(hashmap::get)
            .distinct() // only keep distinct values
            .limit(2).count() == 1 // there should only be one distinct value
    ).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: ok works fine, is it also possible to mark the output somehow, to see which set belongs to the values (1,2) of the hashmap ?
something like :
[set1] + hashset.getValue
[set2] + hashset.getValue

Comment: @lz01 Yes, rather than `forEach`, you can use `Collectors.toMap`: use each set as keys, and use the result from `hashmap.get` as values. This would involve accessing `hashmap` again. I can't think of a stream solution that only accesses the map once.

Comment: ok, im not sure if i understood your answer correctly, could you implement it in your code above?

Comment: I don't think it's a particularly good solution, and it wasn't part of your original question either, so I don't want to add it into my answer. What I meant was instead of `forEach`, do `.collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> hashmap.get(s.iterator().next())))`. This will give you a `Map<Set<Integer>, Integer>` which you can print out. @lz01