# How to Compare a Key of a HashMap with a Set?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, set, java-stream

I have a `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
```

And a `Set` of `Set`s:

```
Set<Set<Integer>> set = Set.of(Set.of(0, 1, 2), Set.of(3, 4, 5));
```

I want to check if 3 of the Keys of the `HashMap` contain 3 Elements of the `Set` and if so check if the values are equal.

for example :

```
hashMap.put(0,1);
hashMap.put(1,1);
hashMap.put(2,1);
return true;

hashMap.put(4,2);
hashMap.put(5,2);
hashMap.put(12,2);
return false;
```

is there a possible solution with `stream()`?

Comment: So it's kind of the reverse of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68221457/can-you-compare-the-keys-of-a-hashmap-with-a-set)?

Comment: Looks like he is asking for solution in some programming exercises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd go over the map entries and make sure they all match the keys, since this can be checked regardless of the set. You can achieve this by streaming the entries and using `allMatch`. Then, you can stream over the sets, and for each of them check it's the same size of the map and all the keys match:

```java
return hashMap.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .allMatch(e -> e.getKey().equals(e.getValue())) &&
       set.stream()
          .anyMatch(s -> s.size() == hashMap.size() && s.containsAll(hashMap.keySet()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static boolean test(HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap, Set<Set<Integer>> set) {
    return set.stream()
        .anyMatch(s -> hashMap.keySet().containsAll(s) &&
            s.stream().map(k -> hashMap.get(k)).distinct().count() == 1);
}
```

and

```
Set<Set<Integer>> set = Set.of(Set.of(0, 1, 2), Set.of(3, 4, 5));

HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap1 = new HashMap<>(Map.of(0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1));
System.out.println(hashMap1 + " : " + test(hashMap1, set));

HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap2 = new HashMap<>(Map.of(4, 2, 5, 2, 12, 2));
System.out.println(hashMap2 + " : " + test(hashMap2, set));
```

output:

```
{0=1, 1=1, 2=1} : true
{12=2, 4=2, 5=2} : false
```